# Postman oauth2 with nodejs

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0, postman

I'm want to test the oauth2 (nodejs) in postman.

So, I made this route:

```
router.get('/authorise', (req, res, next) => {
    console.log('in authorise');

});
```

Postman, I set this Url (which point to my route):

[image]

It's work. It gets to this route. but I am not able to find how to close this window and get the token?

What should the response look like?

I searched everywhere on the web and could not find any information about it.

I have try this but still not working:

```
router.get('/authorise', (req, res, next) => {
        console.log('in authorise');
        res.writeHead(302, { 
          Location: 'https://www.getpostman.com/oauth2/callback?access_token=8ba64c1fbe8d4c3a892e432425842adde38fbb0e&response_type=code' 
        });
        res.end();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to open the window from the client side not from the Node application and when you receive the response from Node you can close the window.

Comment: I'm testing the app using POSTMAN. when I click on the button "Request Token" (in postman) is popup new window ("/authorise").
and there should be user/password fields. but I want to skip to fill them now. I want to be able to pass the flow.

Comment: Are you in testing phase?
If yes then one way or another you have to request the token from a client application.

Comment: Yes. but for now I want to send a fake token and fake refresh token. just for postman will accept them.

Comment: The problem is I dont know what to send to `https://www.getpostman.com/oauth2/callback` to confirm the request and get the token!

Comment: Instead of using Postman to generate oauth2 tokens, you can implement oauth2 by yourself in your Node application by using passportjs with oauth2 strategy.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/passport-oauth2

Comment: Yes. I know, but I want also to support POSTMAN.

Answer (score 0):

I Found!

Just need to return AUTHORIZATION_CODE like so:

```
res.redirect(url.format({
        pathname: "https://www.getpostman.com/oauth2/callback",
        query: {
            code: `AUTHORIZATION_CODE`
        }        
 }));
```

Then is continue to `Access Token Url`.